# Is it possible to animate each line of text with jquery?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to reveal text one line at at time in jquery? I know it can be done in flash I have an example here http://iliketoplay.dk/#/blog/deff. On the video playing, the mouse clicks a circle  which opens a box that contains text but each line of text is displayed one at a time with a really cool looking effect. Can it be recreated?

Comment: You could wrap each word in a span and try to index them with line and column, then animate them. I'll give it a shot and get back to ya.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This shouldn't be a problem, but the solution depends on your input format. You need to chunk up the text in lines which can be done like this:

```
var lines = text.split("\n");
```

Then you can do something with each line as you desire, e.g:

```
var timer, 
  displayLine = function(){
    var nextLine = lines.shift();
    if(nextLine){
      var newLine = $('<span class="initState">' + nextLine + '</span>');
      $('#someContainer').append(newLine);
        newLine.animate({ [PUT SOME ANIMATION HERE] }, 1000);
      }
      timer = setTimeout(displayLine,3000);
    }
  }
timer = setTimeout(displayLine,3000);
```

See a complete example here: http://jsfiddle.net/7dd52/

Comment: The initState class should be styled so that the element appears where you want the animation to start. E.g. height:0; margin-top:-20px;overflow:hidden; etc.

Comment: thanks alot. 
can I add easing into this? by adding easing: 'easeoutExpo' somewhere for example?

Comment: Sure, check the documentation for the animate function: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ Just add the easing parameter as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You just use div for each line and then animate that certain ...

```
<div class="first">first line</div>
<div class="second">second</div>

$(".first").animate({'left':'-15px'}, 1000);
```

Comment: I wouldn't use that, I don't know what the text would be, I think it should be done dynamically.