# Transition opacity text top to down

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `div`, with a given `height`, that transitions to a bigger `height` using jQuery. Transition to taller `div` is smoothed with `transition` element. Since `div` expansion transition is `linear`, with a delay of .5 s, I also use `transition` to shift 7 lines of text from `opacity: 0` to `opacity:1`. However, I want this transition to go top to down (line 1 a bit faster than line 2, a bit faster than line 3, etc.), following `div` transition, instead of all lines at once at once. How to do that? Code below:

```js
    $("small").on("click", function() {
      $(".post1").toggleClass("show-post");
    });
```

```css
.post1 {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width:33%;
  height:125px;
  padding:0 10px;
  border-radius:4px;
  background:#FFFFFF;
  color:black;
  transition: height 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.5s;
}

.descr {
  opacity:0;
}

small {
  position:relative;
  left:300px;
  bottom:30px;
}

.show-post {
  height:350px;
}

.show-post .descr{
  opacity:1;
  transition:opacity 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post1">
    <h4>THis is a concert</h4>
    <p>Where: XYZ Arena</p>
    <p>When: XYZ h</p>
    <small>(Click to expand)</small>
    <p class="descr">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
```

Update:

Now my code looks like:

```js
 <script>
    $("small").on("click", function() {
      $(this).parent().toggleClass("show-post");
      $(".first").animate({'opacity':1}, 1000);
      $(".second").animate({'opacity':1}, 2000);
      $(".third").animate({'opacity':1}, 3000);
      $(".fourth").animate({'opacity':1}, 4000);
      $(".fifth").animate({'opacity':1}, 5000);
      $(".sixth").animate({'opacity':1}, 6000);
      $(".seventh").animate({'opacity':1}, 7000);
      $(".eight").animate({'opacity':1}, 8000);
    });
    
  </script>
```

```css
.descr {
  opacity:0;
}

.first, .second, .third {
  opacity:0;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post">
    <h4>THis is a concert</h4>
    <p>Where: XYZ Arena</p>
    <p>When: XYZ h</p>
    <small>(Click to expand)</small>
    <p class="descr">
      <div class="first">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed </div><div class="second">do eiusmod temporincididunt ut labore et dolore magna </div><div class="third">aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</div><div class="fourth"> ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div><div class="fifth"> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse </div><div class="sixth">cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat </div><div class="seventh">cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit </div><div class="eight">anim id est laborum.</div>
    </p>
  </div>
```

I haven't added yet all `class` in the css code but I can see that it works because I can set a different timing for each transition for each line. Now, here goes a rookie question: how can I select all divs under `.descr` without having to create an extra css element and referring to each individual `.class` under it: `.first, .second, .third`. Tried `.descr, div` but doesn't work. And it's such an easy question that no one asks it and, therefore, can't find answer.

Comment: thanks for the edit @Rachel, question looks nicer now indeed. Do you have also an answer to my question? thanks!

Comment: i have a few show/hide tricks but not one that suits your needs i don't think. I will have a little look

Comment: have been looking around, I've learnt ways to transition `div` up, right, left, etc. but I haven't found anything for the actual text. Any tip, will be welcome!

Comment: **[This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538487/is-it-possible-to-animate-each-line-of-text-with-jquery)** question may help you.

Comment: I was just about to make an answer before he posted that comment that you could set an interval and display your post in paragraphs at intervals

Comment: This might help https://css-tricks.com/text-fade-read-more/

Comment: you could use toggle visibility on the p s

Comment: thank you guys! I've updated my answer because it works, but I have now another answer, which is probably super easy for you guys to answer. Thanks

Comment: can you post a fiddle of your new code with css? thanks

Comment: FYI: `p` is not allowed to contain `div`, you are creating invalid HTML here. Use `span` instead of `div`.

Comment: @CBroe, good catch! that is why :) Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div p div` will select all the divs under descr.

Edit: I have made a section (with the toggle css and repeated animation) which works

I have used paragraphs instead of divs for your lines and a section to hold them all in.

```js
$("small").on("click", function () {

    $(this).parent().toggleClass("show-post");
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass ("show-post") && ($('.show-post').css('height') == '500px')) {
    $(".first").animate({
        'opacity': 1
    }, 1000);
    $(".second").animate({
        'opacity': 1
    }, 2000);
    $(".third").animate({
        'opacity': 1
    }, 3000);
    $(".fourth").animate({
        'opacity': 1
    }, 4000);
    $(".fifth").animate({
        'opacity': 1
    }, 5000);
    $(".sixth").animate({
        'opacity': 1
    }, 6000);
    $(".seventh").animate({
        'opacity': 1
    }, 7000);
    $(".eight").animate({
        'opacity': 1
    }, 8000);

} else if (!$(this).parent().hasClass ("show-post")) {
    $(".first").animate({
        'opacity': 0
    }, 1000);
    $(".second").animate({
        'opacity': 0
    }, 2000);
    $(".third").animate({
        'opacity': 0
    }, 3000);
    $(".fourth").animate({
        'opacity': 0
    }, 4000);
    $(".fifth").animate({
        'opacity': 0
    }, 5000);
    $(".sixth").animate({
        'opacity': 0
    }, 6000);
    $(".seventh").animate({
        'opacity': 0
    }, 7000);
    $(".eight").animate({
        'opacity': 0
    }, 8000);

}
});
```

```css
div section p {
  opacity: 0;
}
.post {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin: 20px auto;
    width:200px;
    height:155px;
    padding:0 10px;
    border-radius:4px;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    color:black;
    transition: height 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.show-post {
    height:500px;
    opacity:1;
    transition:opacity 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post">
  <h4>This is a concert</h4>
  <p>Where: XYZ Arena</p>
  <p>When: XYZ h</p>
  <small>(Click to expand)</small>
  <section class="descr">
    <p class="first">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed</p>
    <p class="second">do eiusmod temporincididunt ut labore et dolore magna</p>
    <p class="third">aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</p>
    <p class="fourth">ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <p class="fifth">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse</p>
    <p class="sixth">cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat</p>
    <p class="seventh">cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit</p>
    <p class="eight">anim id est laborum.</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/yufyqhhf/)

Comment: you are a super star, thanks! I'm at early stages of jQuery learning, I have learnt a thing or two with your post.

Comment: as a sidenote, i would advise that you use 500ms intervals as opposed to 1000. 8 secs is a long time for this animation and the shorter interval works better. - http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/z1h7r7d6